# How to populate active directory users data in a sharepoint 2010 new list item form?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, active-directory

I have a custom list in my SharePoint 2010 website. When I am adding a new item to my list, I want to populate data from active directory in the respective fields when I enter the exact user Id in my first field. Can it be done through SharePoint designer or through browser?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what user information you want to populate into the list, you may find it easier to use the SharePoint API directly and call the SPUser object instead.

```
SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(listItem["UserField""]);
```

The EnsureUser() method will require you to give it a username in the format: domain\user.

That being said, you'd probably behoove yourself to just make the field in question an SPUser field in the first place. That way the default new item / editor makes the field uses the PeoplePicker object to bring in actual users. If you do need to call Active Directory directly, you can do that, too, I guess, but since virtually everything in AD can be exposed in SharePoint either automatically or by editing your User Profile Service application, there's not really a reason to invoke AD directly in most scenarios.